# How to change the calendar to Gregorian in Thailand locale

Tags: java, calendar, internationalization, locale

In my Java 8u51 application, I need to use Thailand locale.
However, I would like to use Gregorian Calendar instead of Buddhist Calendar.

I tried to replace java.util.Calendar 's CalendarProvider with SPI, but it has not worked out.

```
import java.security.AccessController;
...
import sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter;
import sun.util.spi.CalendarProvider;
...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(AccessController.doPrivileged(new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("java.locale.providers")));

        Locale l = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
        CalendarProvider provider = LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(CalendarProvider.class, l).getCalendarProvider();
        provider.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), l);

        LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapterPreference().forEach(o -> System.out.printf("Adapter: %s%n", o));
        System.out.printf("Provider: %s%n", provider.getClass());
        System.out.printf("Availables: %s%n", Calendar.getAvailableCalendarTypes());
        System.out.printf("Calendar: %s%n", Calendar.getInstance().getClass());
    }
    ...
```

`src/META-INF/services/sun.util.spi.CalendarProvider` is as follows.

```
sun.util.locale.provider.AlwaysGregorianCalendarProviderImpl
```

Omit the source of AlwaysGregorianCalendarProviderImpl.
result,

```
$ java -jar Sample.jar -Djava.locale.providers=SPI -Duser.language=th -Duser.country=TH
SPI
Adapter: SPI
Adapter: FALLBACK
Provider: class sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarProviderImpl
Availables: [gregory, buddhist, japanese]
Calendar: class sun.util.BuddhistCalendar
```

Buddhist Calendar will be used.
How can I change it to a Gregorian calendar?

Comment: When using Java 8, there’s no reason (that I can see) why you would want to use `GregorianCalendar` or any other `Calendar` implementation (subclass). Those classes are long outdated, and [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. Its standard classes use the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) no matter the locale.

Comment: You can also simply create a `new GregorianCalendar()` when you need it (suggest using a `java.time` class still). This way you are completely explicit that you *want* a gregorian calendar, not whatever's configured in the system.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, as there are lots of java.util.Calendar used in existing code.Therefore, I need to leave java.util.Calendar as it, and make it a gregorian calendar.

Comment: SPI was never intended for limiting implementations available to Java runtime - it does the opposite. Instead, your application code has to disclose reliance on specific implementation of calendar, if there is any. A simple search-replace job is more than enough if you want to make it a gregorian calendar, even if scope of this change is huge.

Comment: There is also no such thing as `sun.util.locale.provider.AlwaysGregorianCalendarProviderImpl`. The only ref Google search engine knows of that class points to this question.

Comment: This problem exists in my framework part and there are several users, so it is difficult to solve with replacement. It is also difficult if java.util.Calendar is used inside the external library. Therefore, I want to change the contents while keeping it as java.util.Calendar. AlwaysGregorianCalendarProviderImpl is SPI implementation class that I prepared.Implementation has no meaning, as it has not been able to change by SPI.

Comment: There appears to be [no actual SPI for CalendarProvider](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/util/locale/provider/SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java) specifically. Other types of locale resource providers are there, just not that one. So, my suggestion for a fix still applies. If you can't search-replace your whole project including libraries (a fair problem), you certainly can identify and address it in code that requires to have gregory calendars. In the end of the day, treat all of them as `Instants`, identify them by their `millis` value.

Comment: Thanks, I do not yet understand, but have you suggested to check all instances of `java.util.Calendar`? I want to avoid modifying every part. I'm sorry if my understanding was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self reply late.
The SPI implementation by Sun did not allow external expansion. It also checks the filenames of the divided inner classes.
Although I did not investigate in detail, it seems that it can not cope even with CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.